# Image and Clipart and "Bad" Text

Tags: android

For the newest Android SDK, when simply creating a new Android project, does anyone else encounter this simple but weird problem: When you come to the second page "Configure Launcher Icon", Choosing Image or Clipart are both going to create the project successfully, but choosing Text is going to only get all empty packages and no `project.properties` file.

Is that a bug that needs a report? Is this a common issue?

[image]